# magento1.8.0 facing issues at checkout page

Tags: php, magento, onestepcheckout

We are facing issues at checkout. I'm using Magento Community 1.8.0 and my checkout module is Idev's Onestepcheckout. We are getting customer feedback that some times the checkout page is not responding well. We have enabled the logging and we don't find any entry for mysql/db issue for lock wait time or anything. if any of you face this kind of issue or have any idea about this issue, please help me out in this case.

Comment: Idev's Onestepcheckout - it is a real hell!!!
Such freeze appear for example with sagepay module. The trouble is in js. SagePay override some form action (place order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just Idev's checkout though but unfortunately so many other OnePageCheckout solutions as well.

The thing here is to effectively arrive at a solution and track errors. If you purchased the module, get support! If not, I suggest you install better client-side (mostly Javascript) error tracking such as TrackJS. http://trackjs.com/

Server side, just rely on exception logs and web server logs. Better yet, get NewRelic, too.

There's no shame in using tools. Finding out which works tends to be a battle in itself.